# SVG based slider bar with VueJS

Tags: svg, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to implement a range slider with SVG. I've built the SVG format with tags. Now I am trying to do click operand. If the end-user clicks anywhere on the bar, the bar needs to move there.

SVG Format:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" :viewBox="'0 0 '+side+' 15'" ref="_svg" @click="handleClick">
    <line x1="250" y1="7" x2="0" y2="7" stroke="#334860" stroke-width="3"></line>
    <path :d="'M 0 7 l '+position+' 0'" stroke="#00be7e" stroke-width="3" fill="none"></path>
    <text :x="(position)-1.5" y="3" font-size="3" style="fill:red;">99</text>
    <circle :cx="position" cy="7" r="1.5" stroke="#00be7e" stroke-width="3" fill="#00be7e"></circle>
</svg>
```

as you can see from the above, the SVG file contains a viewBox attribute. I am setting it on the data function of the component. Also, there is a position variable on the there which handles the bar location.

Component Script:

```
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            side:250,
            position: 125
        };
    },
    methods: {
        handleClick (e) {
            this.position = e.x/this.$refs._svg.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        },
    }
}
```

The handle click function is triggering while user clicked somewhere on the bar. However, the issue is it is not setting the correct location of clicked zone. What is the best practice about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is with the calculation of scrub's X position.
I changed the code this way and it seems working:

`this.position = e.clientX - this.$refs._svg.getBoundingClientRect().left;`

Also to dont allow user click around the bar , probably adding a Min/Max to the calculation can improve it this way:

```
var pos = e.clientX - this.$refs._svg.getBoundingClientRect().left;
var refined = Math.max(pos, 0);
    refined = Math.min(refined, this.side);

this.position = refined;
```

I just also prepared a fiddle that you can test:

https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadm/qqvj08b5/

Hope it helps